# Adding classes to the 'body' of various different Shop pages

Tags: jquery, regex, squarespace

I'm building a shop and trying to add a different `body` class to three pages. These are the three pages:

1) The main page: `example.com/shop/`

2) The item page: `example.com/shop/model-xxxx/`

3) The category page: `example.com/shop/?category=xxxx/`

**Here's what I tried:**

```
if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/shop/.+')) ) {

    jQuery('body').addClass('shop-item');

} else if (window.location.href.match('/shop/')) {

    jQuery('body').addClass('shop');

} else if (window.location.href.match('/shop/?category=')) {

    jQuery('body').addClass('shop-category');

}
```

Ideally, the `/shop/` page would have the class of `shop` added to the `body`, the `/shop/model-xxxx/` page would have the class of `shop-item` added to the `body`, and the `/shop/?category=xxxx/` page would have the class of `shop-category` added to the `body`.

The first two work, but the category page gets `shop-item` added as a class instead of `shop-category` because that rule is defined in the first line.

---

**Question:** How do I make sure that the `shop-category` class gets added to the category pages?

Comment: Make your last check (`'/shop/?category='`) the first check.

Comment: @mpf82 I tried that but the category pages are still getting the `shop-item` class instead of the `shop-category` class. Here is the code reordered: https://jsfiddle.net/wzxzcaw4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, JS does not like to match escaped question marks if you're using quotes around the expression.

This is tested and works:

```js
function checkUrl(url) {
  if (url.match(/\/shop\/\?category/)) {
    console.log(url, "-> category");
  } else if (url.match(new RegExp('/shop/.+'))) {
    console.log(url, "-> item");
  } else if (url.match('/shop/')) {
    console.log(url, "-> shop");
  }
}


checkUrl('exmaple.com/shop/');
checkUrl('exmaple.com/shop/?category=blub');
checkUrl('exmaple.com/shop/other');
```

Comment: Thank you. Moving 'categories' to the top and escaping the characters worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [negative-lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your first rule.

```
if (window.location.href.match(new RegExp('/shop/(?!\?category).+')) ) {

    jQuery('body').addClass('shop-item');

} else ...
```

This while ensure that your second part of URL does not start with ?category